# Foreach ul li as an infinity condition

Tags: laravel, loops, for-loop

I have the below table:

```
public function up()
{
    Schema::create('locations', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->string('location_name',50);
        $table->integer('location_id')->unsigned();
        $table->foreign('location_id')->references('id')->on('locations');          
        $table->softDeletes();
        $table->timestamps();
    });
}
```

Where I want it to look like a tree, but still be able to use it in my ul li drop down list.
Inside my blade I've done this:

```
                    <ol>
                        @foreach($locations->where('location_id','=',null) as $location)
                            <li draggable='true'>
                                {{$location->location_name}}
                                <ol>
                                @foreach($location->get_sub as $location_sub)
                                    <li draggable='true'>{{$location_sub->location_name}}</li>
                                @endforeach
                                </ol>
                            </li>
                        @endforeach
                    </ol>
```

$location->get_sub is function inside the model 
for relationship

```
public function get_sub()
{
    return $this->hasMany('App\Location','location_id','id');
}
```

By doing so I can reach the parent/child location; however, sometimes I need an elements parent's child's grand-grand-grandchild etc. 
My idea to do this is to make a while loop to look for every child location and 
and put them in ul li list and every get_sub to show it under it with ul li inside the parent ul li to looks like this:

[image]

Sometimes though the location gets 7 fathers and if I know the number of fathers I can make while loop for as many as fathers numbers but I don't know the number at compile time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How's your model called? Lets suppose it's named Location. Add your relationship name to the $with property in your Location model:

```
protected $with = ['get_sub'];
```

In your controller (or wherever you are doing it) you can call:

```
$locations = Location::get();
```

You'll get that nested list. But be careful if your list grows up too much. Every time you fetch a location from db, it will come with all of it's children. So, check if you can dynamically add or remove that 'get_sub' item from your $with array.

To start from the child you need to define a parent() method in your Location model, and add it to the $with array.

```
protected $with = ['parent'];

public function parent()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Location', 'location_id', 'id');
}
```

Comment: $locations = Location::withTrashed()->get();
  return view('locations.create',compact('locations')); this is my controller code i already did what u said

Comment: my problem thats i want it to start from the last child not from the parent